# C# how to remove a current row from the table by button click

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove a table row from the table:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var task in Model)
    {
        <tr>

                <td>
                    @task.time
                </td>
                <td>
                    @task.descripiton
                </td>
                <td>
                    @task.duedo
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="@Url.Action("Remove")" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form>
                </td>
        </tr>

    }
</tbody>
```

How could I send the index of the row to the controller?

```
public ActionResult Remove()
{
   Task.RemoveAt();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The row where I pressed the button would get removed.

Comment: GWL can you please explain more on what do you want to achieve and what did you try?

Comment: well i made a list 
added the list to html 
so currently it is removing first row if i am pressing the button on the table what as u see i created
but i would like to make it that it will remove the row on which row was the button pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change view code to:

```
<tbody>
@{
    var idx = 0;
    foreach (var task in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @task.time
            </td>
            <td>
                @task.descripiton
            </td>
            <td>
                @task.duedo
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="@Url.Action("Remove", "YourControllerName", new { id = idx++ })" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</tbody>
```

Then, change `Remove` method to:

```
public ActionResult Remove(int id)
{
    Task.RemoveAt(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) i been searching for solution for so long :)